# How do I get my 3ds Max models into an iPhone 3D game?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, ipad

I've written a couple apps that are currently published in the app store. However, I'd like to start writing games that use OpenGL ES. I know how to model objects in 3D Studio Max but what I don't know is how to get my models into an OpenGL ES application on the iPhone/iPad and then manipulate those objects to create gameplay.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get started on this?

Just to clarify...I don't mind writing code; I'm not looking for a point and click solution.

I would imagine that I'd need to export my models into some sort of format. What is that format and how do I incorporate it into a game on the iPhone/iPad?

Answer (score 2):

While more involved than you're looking for, Stephen Jayna has [a great writeup](http://www.everita.com/lightwave-collada-and-opengles-on-the-iphone) on how he exported textured models from LightWave in COLLADA format for use in OpenGL ES on the iPhone.

Bill Dudney had put a little effort into making a [Wave Front OBJ loader](http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/wave_front_obj_textures_working) for the iPhone a while back, but I think that [Jeff LaMarche's project](http://code.google.com/p/iphonewavefrontloader/) to do the same might be the farthest along.

UPDATE (8/10/2011): Jonathan Wight recently posted [his TouchOpenGL code](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchOpenGL), which includes an OBJ parser.

Comment: I tried the Wave Front OBJ loader today and ran into a few issues. From what I can gather, the loader requires the models to be exported in a certain way, and my OBJs weren't exported in that way and thus I ended up with strange looking models and it took 5 mins to load one of them on device. I'm researching assimp and aiObjectiveC next...

Comment: @Ben - You could also try out Jonathan Wight's TouchOpenGL, which I link to above.  Several others have worked on OBJ importers since I originally wrote my answer.

Comment: Ah I didn't notice that. Thanks. I will look that up too.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [this](http://code.google.com/p/lib3ds/) before with some luck.  However, I would say there are no easy answers to this in my experience.  They all required some coding/wiring up for me.

Comment: Thats library is on my TODO list to research. Do you have any code samples, videos of finished product or an app in the app store that I could look at? I'm trying to get a skeletal rigged 3DS model to play on an iPhone using OpenGL.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nightmare process. My past approach to this was probably not the best. I worked on PC using 3DS Max to create an exporter using MaxScript. I dumped what I needed to a text file - in a format that I just invented for my own needs as an intermediate.

I then switched to Mac and wrote a command line tool that used NSFoundation to read this text file and convert it to a binary format that was optimized for my opengl renderer. This is okay for basic and static meshes. But I had hell exporting animated figures that used keyframed skelaton animations (the maths for that stuff is intense).

This did work, but I really think that I took the hardest approach.

Comment: +1'd this just because you're awesome for pulling it off this way. Those maths do get pretty crazy :)